# Xpath returning array with 2 elements but selecting the index of it doesn't work and return the array it self

Tags: c#, arrays, xpath, automated-tests

My xpath need to return a link that is inside an array, but when I try to select the link inside the array using `[1]` the complete array is returned.

This is my array `li7 = [a, a.link]` and I'm trying to get `li7[1]`, but my return is `[a,a.link]`

When I try to see what is inside my first element of the array (`li7[0]`) an empty array is returned.

I don't know what to do anymore

Answer (score 0):

While XPath 3.1 has arrays, it is not clear whether and how you use try to use them. Consider to both show the input XML and the C# code that fails. In XPath 3.1, an array is a function, you access the first item with e.g. `$a(1)` or `$a?1` but not with `$a[1]`, the positional predicate is what you use in XPath for node-sets (XPath 1) or sequences of items (XPath 2 and later). Whatever your XPath expression is, if `exp` selects those two elements and you want only a single one use `(exp)[1]`.